# Google Cloud Storage - ListObjects, folder are not shown.

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I am trying out Google Cloud Storage, and have a problem with its C# SDK. Specifically, I have created a bucket with folder a/, b/, c/ (with files in folder). When I use:

```
gsutil ls gs://<mybucket>/root/
```

The folders correctly show up as:

```
gs://<mybucket>/root/a
gs://<mybucket>/root/b
gs://<mybucket>/root/c
```

However, when I use C# SDK to list the folder,

```
var client = StorageClient.Create();
var opt = new ListObjectsOptions() { Delimiter = "/" };
var ret = client.ListObjects("<mybucket>", "root/", opt);
var lst = new List<Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object>(); 
foreach (var item in ret )
{
    lst.Add(item);
}
```

The resultant list is empty (no folder returned). Note if I change the code above to:

```
var opt = new ListObjectsOptions();
```

All files in the folder can be successfully listed. What is wrong? Can ListObjects with Delimiter options list the folder in the storage bucket?

Comment: Have you tried `root` instead of `root/` for the prefix?

Comment: I tried both "root". Same problem (gsutil returned 3 folders, C# SDK returned none).

Comment: have you solved this problem? same issue here

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem with the C# library... in December 2022!

Comment: Identical problem in 2023, in the rest response can see the data returning prefix but it's coming back as empty array in the code.

Answer (score -2):

In API reference [Delimiter](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.ListObjectsOptions.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_ListObjectsOptions_Delimiter) is described as following:

> Used to list in "directory mode". Only objects whose names (aside from the prefix) do not contain delimiter will be returned.

Basically you have to set Delimiter to empty

```
var opt = new ListObjectsOptions() { Delimiter = "" };
```

Otherwise it ignores every folder in your bucket. Just set Delimiter to empty and the rest of your code will work.

Comment: I need to list directories. If Delimiter is set to "", it will list all files under the prefix. This is not what I want. The issue here is that the .Net API of Google Cloud Storage behaves differently from gsutil.